# Proper way to insert a .pem cert into OpenSSL / a rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, openssl

I have a .pem cert that I'm reasonably sure I generated correctly, and it is not being accepted by OpenSSL when I paste it into a Rails 3.0.2 model. What I do is this:

```
open up the .pem file in Textmate
select all and copy
user.cert = <paste into model>; user.save
OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(user.cert)
```

This gives me the error:

```
Neither PUB key nor PRIV key::
```

To test, I just loaded in the file instead, no errors:

```
OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("/path/to/cert.pem"))
```

I thought maybe it would be some encoding error or newline issue, I had tried gsub'ing out the newlines to no avail.

Comment: Post the steps you used to create the certificate in the first place to ensure that your certificate actually contains a private key.

Comment: looks to me like it is some copy-and-paste artifact. maybe not newlines, but some other sort of spacing issues. it's hard to say without actually seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a weird copy and paste artifact indeed. I File.read'd it into the model instead of copy paste and it worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps late, but this is the answer:
You can put a public key inline in Ruby with copy/paste, but keep in mind that what looks like formatting to you is white space in the line - you need to make sure that the resulting pem string has no spaces. I just copied and pasted from a PEM file into Ruby code, and it did not work until I removed the extra spaces that text mate or whatever added to the lines.

Hard to show here:

SQS_PUBLIC_KEY = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAs3VeTxEgLQLL11UN2G6c
oQsc0LbpoEs4VTmu0S4XU82N4h/25XX5k4t5oTJ0JGGSBP4/gzTwz15vS5mrlnsG
MISSINGLINES
rMV5ZCXToG0VCNPEHpZQnUHMCg/nF9jnk9i1ZZHv2dpYYG7GHMUPG3rtcTWJvZxI
3wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----".force_encoding("us-ascii")

```
SQS_PUBLIC_KEY = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
  MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAs3VeTxEgLQLL11UN2G6c
  oQsc0LbpoEs4VTmu0S4XU82N4h/25XX5k4t5oTJ0JGGSBP4/gzTwz15vS5mrlnsG
  MISSINGLINES
  rMV5ZCXToG0VCNPEHpZQnUHMCg/nF9jnk9i1ZZHv2dpYYG7GHMUPG3rtcTWJvZxI
  3wIDAQAB
  -----END PUBLIC KEY-----".force_encoding("us-ascii")
```

ie - NOT the second one - ruby adds spaces to the start of each line, and the RSA tools do not ignore spaces - they only seem to ignore line feeds.

I use the copy/pasted key as a fallback - in other words if an ENV is set I use that, otherwise use the pasted in public key.

--Tom